# The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, arch-linux

I installed VirtualBox and it has not worked after all the solutions I've tried. When I start VirtualBox it does nothing but when I try to run a VM it gives the following error:

```
The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly.
Please try setting it up again by executing
'/sbin/vboxconfig'
as root.
(stuff about EFI secure boot, which isn't enabled on my laptop)
```

I tried to run that command but it just couldn't find the file.

I also checked out some errors in the cli with

```
VBoxManage --version
```

it gives me this

```
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (5.6.15-arch1-1) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

           sudo /sbin/vboxconfig

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
6.1.10r138449
```

Another thing I tried was to load vboxdrv with:

```
modprobe vboxdrv
```

I just got:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found in directory /lib/modules/5.6.15-arch1-1
```

A list of other things I tried:

- I tried updating the system and packages with pacman -Syyu.
- I tried reinstalling VBox.
- I tried reinstalling linux-headers.
- I installed vbox-host-dkms and vbox-guest-dkms

Comment: What version of the 'linux' package do you have _installed_?

Comment: linux 5.7.2.arch1-1

Comment: Odd. The only solution I have found online is to simply uninstall the VirtualBox you installed via package installer and install [VirtualBox via the official installers](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=99564).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the thread necromancy, but I fixed it in case, anyone comes across this thread from DDG (as I did), on arch with `sudo pacman -Syu linux-headers` and a restart.